# How can i copy to string literal in C

Tags: c

```
char temp1[4] = "abc";
char *temp2 = "123";
strcpy(temp1,temp2);
```

if I want to copy a string literal to an array, it works well, but if I do it in the opposite way, I get an error:

```
char temp1[4] = "abc";
char *temp2 = "123";
strcpy(temp2,temp1);
```

The feedback from compiler is "Segmentation fault".

So what's the differences? Is there anyway to copy a string to a string literal?

Thx.

Comment: Because writing a string literal in C is has an undefined behavior.

Comment: You assign a constant to `temp2`. That is, `temp2` points to a constant buffer. You cannot "write" (or copy) into it.

Comment: By the way, "Segmentation fault" is a feedback that does not come from compiler.

Comment: _"Is there anyway to copy a string to a string literal?"_ Why?

Answer (score 2):

You need to understand the subtle difference between these 2 lines

```
char temp1[4] = "abc";
char *temp2 = "123";
```

The first one creates a 4 character variable and copies "abc\0" to it.
You can overwrite that if you want to. You can do e.g. `temp1[0] = 'x'` if you want.

The second one creates a pointer that points to the constant literal "123\0".
You cannot overwrite that, its typically in memory that is declared read only to the OS.

Comment: as i was typing i thought "remeber to add one for the 0", then I did it twice :-(

Answer (score 1):

What you have is more complicated than a string literal and what you attempt to do cannot be described as "copying to string literal". Which is good, because copying to a string literal is literally impossible. (Excuse the pun.)

First, what you are successfully doing in the first code quote is copying **from** a string literal into an array of chars of size 4 (you knew that). You are however doing this with the added detail of copying via a pointer to that string literal (`temp2`). Also note that what the pointer is pointing to is not a variable which can be edited in any way. It is "just a string which the linker knows about".

In the second code quote you attempt to copy a string (strictly speaking a zero-terminated sequence of chars which is stored in an array, `temp1`, but not a string literal) to a place where a pointer to char (`temp2`) points to, but which happens not to be a variable which is legal to write to.

The types of the involved variables allow such an operation basically, but in this case it is forbidden/impossible; which causes the segmentation fault.

Now what IS possible and might be what you actually attempt, is to repoint `temp2` to the address at the beginning of `temp1`.  I believe that is what gives you the desired effect:

```
char temp1[4] = "abc";
char *temp2 = "123";

/* Some code, in which temp2 is used with a meaningful
   initialisation value, which is represented by "123".
   Then, I assume you want to change the pointer, so that it points
   to a dynamically determined string, which is stored in a changeable
   variable.
   To do that: */
temp2=temp1;
/* But make sure to keep the variable, the name you chose makes me worry. */
```

Note that an array identifier can be used as a pointer to the type of the array entries.

Comment: Your last edit is confusing me. If that is what user wanted, why even assign `temp2 = "123"`?

Comment: Good point. I will explain an assumption I had... Thanks. @AGNGazer

Comment: I just do not think OP was attempting anything except for trying to learn by trial.

Comment: Also possible. I think a little "you could do something very similar" is helpful for that purpose, too. @AGNGazer

Comment: By the way, this makes it slightly different from the proposed duplicate...