# char * , strcat interaction .why doesnt it print anything

Tags: c

It prints nothing.I think the problem is at the type char * but i dont know if and why.

```
int main() {
    char *a = "0123456789" ;
    char *b = "abcdefghij" ;
    strcat (a,b) ;
    printf( "%s", a ) ;
}
```

Comment: This code should segfault.

Comment: `a`is a string literal value that cannot be modified. Allocate a destination buffer at runtime.

Comment: Nothing.No errors.

Comment: There was [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50688580/how-can-i-copy-to-string-literal-in-c) just few questions ago.

Comment: What platform are you running on?

Comment: That should explain.Thanks.I run it on c

Comment: @merlin2011: Such code is likely to seg fault, but I don't see any particular basis for saying it "should".

Comment: Writing/appending to a _string literal_ like  `"0123456789"` is _undefined behavior_.  It might "work", it might not.  It is UB.

Comment: Yup.Its been mentioned but thanks anyways.Any way i can mark this question as answered?

Comment: @Loga, merlin was asking whether you were running on Windows, Linux, Mac, some microcontroller, etc., not the language you are programming in.

Comment: Nvm ill upvote the answer.Its windows 10^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`strcat` modifies the `destination` parameter buffer, [but `a`'s buffer is in read-only memory as it's a string literal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2589949/string-literals-where-do-they-go).

The solution is to create a buffer at runtime and use that as the buffer. You'll need to copy `a` into it first, of course.

```
char* a = "1234567890";
char* b = "abcdefghij";

size_t aLen = strlen( a );

char* combined = malloc( sizeof(char) * ( strlen(a) + strlen(b) + 1 ) );
strcpy_s( combined, aLen, a ); // always use _s versions of string/buffer functions!
strcat( combined, b );

puts( combined );

free( combined );
```

Alternatively in C99 we could just use a stack-allocated array that's preinitialized (and preallocated to be large enough). Stack arrays, including pre-initialized ones, *can* have their buffer written to:

```
char a[100] = "1234567890";
strcat( a, "abcdefghij" );
puts( a );
```

Comment: It's not really necessary to initialize the memory to zero if you are immediately going to overwrite it.  Also not a fan of consecutive `strcat` calls as it is the textbook example of a Shlemiel The Painter's algorithm.

Comment: `char combined` -> `char *combined`

Comment: Is it in read-only memory? Are you sure the implementation has that? If you base your answer on a comment, either incorporate it into the question and / or at least point that implementation-dependency out in the answer. Why `calloc()` instead of `malloc()`, or even better an automatic array?

Comment: While the OP did mention they are using Windows, I would generally shy away from windows-specific libraries when avoidable.  In this case, since dealing with string literals, they are guaranteed to be null-terminated, so you can safely use the standard `strcpy`.

Comment: @ChristianGibbons I've added a 3-line answer that uses a preinitialized stack array.

Comment: @ChristianGibbons I didn't use any Windows-specific functions. `strcat` and `calloc` are both in the standard library and "Portable C" conventions dictate string literals are read-only.

Comment: @Dai the windows-specific function was was referring to was `strcpy_s`.  Unless I am mistaken, that is a microsoft function for safer string manipulation.

Comment: @ChristianGibbons The `_s` functions were added to C11. I think they started-out as Microsoft extensions around 2003-2005? But they're standard now.

Comment: Oh really?  Good to know.

Comment: @ChristianGibbons The `_s`-functions are in the optional and oft-rejected Annex K of C11. At least an incompatible variant of them. Consider browsing [tag:tr24731].

Answer (score -1):

You cant cat to string literal as dest. Use an array as dest buffer

```
char str[30] = "Ala ";
const char *strFrom = "ma kota";
strcat (str, strFrom);
```

**edit: extending the answer**

Take a look how string literals get compiled:
https://godbolt.org/g/hZuR1o

Array buffer is defined inline and it's value is constructed during execution and is located on the stack. Thus the buffer itself can be freely modified.

If you allocated it dynamically (with malloc or calloc), you'd get a pointer to the buffer on the heap which could be modified as well.

String literals on the other hand land in read-only memory regions and are shared across various instances since they're read-only anyway. That's how it's designed, man:)

Comment: You're right. Edited

Comment: *Why* can't you cat to string literal? *What happens* if I try anyway? Is there any reason you don't use a `const char str[42]` instead? I think this answer could be improved.